# How do i pass this structure to a function? i have a faint idea but need some advice

Tags: c, function

So i have a piece of code that shifts a point (x,y) according to the user inputting an x offset, y offset and rotation(theta). the point is a structure type pointA with float x and float y. I've created functions for the x and y offset but im not sure how to approach the rotation given an angle, i know i need to pass the structure through the function to get the x and y output but im not sure how to do it, some advice please. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float xNew(float x, float x2);
float yNew(float y, float y2);
float Rotate(float x, float y, float angle);

voide main()
{

typedef struct
{
float x;
float y;
}coordinate;

cooardinate pointA;
float x, y, x2, y2;

printf("Enter coordinates>");
scanf("%f%f, &pointA.x, &pointA.y);

printf("Enter x offset>");
scanf(%f, &x2);
x = xNew(pointA.x, x2);

printf("Enter y offset>");
scanf("%f", &y2);
y = yNew(PointA.y, y2);

/*enter rotation call function here*/

printf("offsets were %f%f\n", x2, y2);
printf("rotation was %f degrees\n", theta);
pointA.x = x;
pointA.y = y;
printf("struc coords are now %f%f", pointA.x, pointA.y);
}
printf("new coords are%f%f\n", x, y);

float xNew(float x, float x2)
{
float xpos;

xpos = x + x2;
return(xpos);
}

float yNew(float y, float y2)
{
float ypos;

ypos = y + y2;
return(ypos);

/enter rotation function declaration here*/
}
```

Comment: What is the rotation trying to do? Is it having the point rotate around the origin?

Comment: yes, i was given the formula to do so, being 
cos(angle)*xOriginal - sin(angle)*yOriginal;
sin(angle)*xOriginal + cos(angle)*yOriginal;

i understand whats happening mathemetically, however im not to sure how to put the structure through this function to get a new x and y value (and update my structure). Side not we haven't learnt about pointers yet, just the basics like if, else, loops arrays and structures.

Comment: Note that the lack of indentation makes the code hard to read, especially with a `typedef` inside `main`. There are syntax errors too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rotate function will need to modify a coordinate, you probably should pass the structure as a pointer:

```
void Rotate(coordinate *coord, float angle);
```

Then the function can just update the coordinates with:

```
coord->x = newx;
coord->y = newy;
```

You don't need to return a value as the structure gets modified in place as you are passing a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, passing the struct by pointer is probably the best option. When doing so, the function will look something like this.

```
void Rotate(coordinate* point, float angle){
    //Calculate in radians
    angle = angle/180.0 * M_PI;

    float newX = cos(angle)*point->x - sin(angle)*point->y;
    float newY = sin(angle)*point->x + cos(angle)*point->y;

    point->x = newX;
    point->y = newY;
}
```

An additional thing, you don't need to actually have functions to calculate newX and newY for the offset. You can simply update them like variables.

```
pointA.x += x2;
pointA.y += y2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the structure by reference to the function.  That is, you need to pass a pointer.

```
void Rotate(coordinate *point, float theta);
```

You would then call the function via

```
coordinate point;
point.x=SOME_VALUE;
point.y=SOME_OTHER_VALUE;

Rotate(&point,SOME_ANGLE);
```

Comment: So address to point as an argument, then inside the function i can declare point.x and point.y as variables and use them? Will that output new values for point.x and point.y?

Comment: When passed a pointer to a structure, a function can access the structures elements via `->`.  So, you could directly set the `x` value with `point->x = SOMETHING`.

Comment: Thanks for the input, we haven't covered pointers yet, how do you pass a structure through a function without them?

Comment: You can pass a structure to a function without a pointer.  However, the function will only receive a copy of the structure.  Therefore, any changes the function makes will only be to the copy and not to the original structure.  That's where pointers come in.  Instead of passing a copy of the structure, you give the function the memory location of the structure.  In essence, you're saying to the function, "My data is located here for you to make any changes."

Comment: Ooookay I get i think I get it, so without using pointers the output will be another structure with the altered members from the function and I would have to manually set the output to the original structure members? Is that how it goes?

Comment: That's one way to do it.  However, it's not recommended, in general, to pass structures directly (i.e., without a pointer) to functions.  This is because some structures could be very large in size (maybe several kilobytes) and so your computer will have to copy the very large structure every time the function is called.  With pointers, no matter how big your structure gets, all the computer has to copy is a pointer, which is usually only 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: Okay, I think what I’m really stuck on is when passing a structure to a function, knowing it does operations on a copy of the original structure (whatever declared variables are in there at the time), does it output a copy of the updated structure and then you need to manually set the copy to the original? Does that mean you need to declare a new variable of the structure type and put it through the function and then manually set it to the original members?

Comment: You could set your original variable equal to the return value of the function.  I.e., `my_struct = func(my_struct, angle);`.  However, for the reasons mentioned above, this is not a good idea.  Pointers are essential.

Comment: I’ve been manually updating the members of the structure after every function using the &struct_variable_type.member, and it’s a roundabout approach I agree. But I guess when it comes to further topics it becomes clear as to why you shouldn’t use methods like that